Fill the ACF field who modified the user profile
I'd like to record the user_id or display_name of the user (admin, moderator) who modified the members profile ACF field. Because this field will be use to identify who is the responsible user updated the member profile via email notification plugin. So generally, I need the display_name to be there right away before the user hit the "Update Profile" button.
My current code:
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'member_profile', 20, 2 );
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'member_profile', 20, 2 );
function member_profile( $member_id, $user_id ) {

  update_field( 'field_673bbd254e89a', $user_id->display_name, 'user_'.$member_id );

};

However, I noticed that the user_id->display_name & 'user_'.$member_id don't seem to work in the admin.

You could use javascript which can easily be added with the action 'admin_enqueue_scripts' and actualy fill this field by targeting it's class or id. On submit it will have the value. You can also make the field visually hidden.

First, note that there is only one available argument, which is the WP_User object for your hooked function.
Also, note that edit_user_profile and show_user_profile, are hooks made for displaying input fields on the viewed user profile, but not saving the data when submitted.
So you can try the following slight different, instead:
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'keep_last_edit_user_dname', 20, 1 );
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'keep_last_edit_user_dname', 20, 1 );
function keep_last_edit_user_dname( $user ) {
    global $current_user;

    // If the current user role matches with admin or moderator
    if ( array_intersect( $current_user->roles, ['administrator', 'moderator'] ) ) { 
        // Update the ACF field
        update_field( 'field_673bbd254e89a', $current_user->display_name, $user->ID );
    }
};

But it should grab the current user display name (when it's an administrator or a moderator), each time they visit a user profile, even if they don't make any changes.

A better way
Maybe a better way should be to display a hidden input field with that admin or moderator display name, so the field is updated only when the data is submitted, like:
// Display a hidden input field  with admin/moderator user display name
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'add_last_edit_user_dname', 20, 1 );
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_last_edit_user_dname', 20, 1 );
function add_last_edit_user_dname( $user ) {
    global $current_user;

    // If the current user role matches with admin or moderator
    if ( array_intersect( $current_user->roles, ['administrator', 'moderator'] ) ) { 
        // Display a hidden input field with the admin display name
        printf('<input type="hidden" name="modified_by" value="%s" />', $current_user->display_name );
    }
};

Then when user data is edited via submit, we use the following to update the ACF field:
// Save the ACF field with admin/moderator user display name
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_last_edit_user_dname', 20 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_last_edit_user_dname', 20 );
function save_last_edit_user_dname( $user_id )
{
    if( isset($_POST['modified_by']) && ! empty($_POST['modified_by']) ) {
        // Update the ACF field
        update_field( 'field_673bbd254e89a', esc_attr($_POST['modified_by']), $user_id );
    }
}

This could work in a better way.

Thanks for the answer here. I appreciate it! However, under the "better way" area the 1st code works fine but not the 2nd code... though, i tried to modify the update_field() but still not displaying the value inside the ACF field. What I did is create a jQuery code and pass the value from the hidden to the ACF in your 1st code. And it worked. The only thing that I always noticed that the member id of that profile doesn't pass to the function, unless you hardcoded it like "user_4". Again, thanks for the help.

addition to this, your call to the function keep_last_edit_user_dname is different to the "add_action"

@iMarkDesigns Sorry, yes you are right, I changed the function name to the correct one, and also there was a missing comma inside printf() function. Try "the better way" again, it should work.
